# CocoaLibSpotify login through Spotify app?

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I've integrated CocoaLibSpotify with my iOS app, and I wonder if there's a way to save the user from having to enter credentials if they've already signed in to the Spotify app on their phone.

I know Spotify doesn't support OAuth, but I did want to ask if anybody knows if Spotify (1) plans to support OAuth in the future, or (2) is working on another way to spare the user from re-entering credentials into another app for the same service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with CocoaLibSpotify — the first time the user wants to log in, they have to enter their credentials.

Once that's done, CocoaLibSpotify has APIs for saving the user's credentials and using them next time, though, so the user only should ever have to input their credentials once. To be honest, since an app with OAuth would have authenticate the user once as well, the method CocoaLibSpotify uses isn't really extra effort for user.

Look at the delegate method `session:didGenerateLoginCredentials:forUserName:` to get the credentials after logging in, and the `attemptLoginWithUserName:existingCredential:` to log in again next time.

Comment: The extra effort for the user is that they have to enter their credentials at all. Facebook's method of opening their app and then kicking back to yours may not be the most elegant, but it saves the user from having to type a username and password if they have the Facebook app installed. If I read your answer right, there are no plans to add anything like this, correct?